# Dynamically resize width of textbox with screen size using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox(input control) which I want to resize as per screen size using javascript. Is their a way to do it.
Thanks for the help.

I have tried giving static width using document.getElementById, but not able to resize it dynamically as per webpage size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will set the width of the input equal to the width of the screen (dynamic and on resize):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var windowWidth = window.innerWidth
      $('#myInput').width(windowWidth)
      $(window).resize(function() {
        windowWidth = window.innerWidth
        $('#myInput').width(windowWidth)
      })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps alot, just one question though when applying "window.innerwidth" it's adding a scroll bar as the control width is to the size of window. Is their a way to correct this, maybe assigning width equal to some other control?

Comment: Yes.. if you want to make the scroll bar disappear, just subtract some small amount from the `windowWidth` variable. For example, try this: `var windowWidth = window.innerWidth - 100`. Adjust the `100` according to your liking and until the scroll bar has disappeared. There are also many more methods to make it disappear.

Comment: @ishaanGupta Also, you're welcome. Please mark the answer as "accepted" if it worked for you! Thanks!

Comment: Code works perfectly, just  a small addition i did according to my requirement, was instead of setting width equal to window, I assigned width of another textbox "var windowWidth = $("#input2").width()" to it so both of them are in perfect sync while resizing the window. Still Thank you very much for guiding me through the process.